# Creating web controls inside a content placeholder programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a master page and a content page. How can I add controls to the master page's content placeholders programmatically?

Comment: Did you tried to do such a thing like:

'this.Page.Master.FindControl("myPlaceHolder")'

and add the control to its controls collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like following:

```
this.Master.Controls.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderID").Controls.Add(yourControl);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Page.Master.FindControl
```

As said above would work fine.

Alternatively, make whatever placeholder in your master page a ContentPlaceHolder, and then your child pages can put stuff there directly without having to go up through the Master page.

Comment: Remember that the state of the controls will not automatically saved unless they are created and added during init event. More reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx